# Prevent IntelliJ from creating public visibility class

Tags: class, intellij-idea, visibility

I tried set checkbox in Settings -> Code Style -> Java Default Visibility but it seems doesn't work. This option applies only for methods and perhaps constructors (not sure). I have 2018.1 EAP version

Comment: Could you please clarify your issue? Is it possible to provide steps to reproduce?

Comment: I'm not sure is it issue. I just want to create classes with default package scope. When i type alt + insert -> java class then i have to remove 'public' keyword every time

Comment: You could change defaut tempate in "Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates - Files - Class"

Comment: ohhh great man it works! I was looking for in wrong place, thank you so much :))

Answer (score 3):

Using `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1` on MacOS Monterey this can be done by changing the default template by doing the following steps:

1. Go to Preferences
2. Search for [File and Code Templates]
3. Scroll to 'Class'
4. There can change the template on the right-hand-side to remove the `public` keyword